# RecursiveDirectoryIterator + RecursiveIteratorIterator + RegexIterator are not working like they should

Tags: php, tree, iterator, subdirectory

I like to get all .less files in a Directory with Subdirectories. I have found this nice looking code at [php.net](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.recursivedirectoryiterator.php#97228).

Am I doing something wrong? Has something changed? Is the Example wrong? It looks like the first one finds a .less.bak file.

```
$Directory = new RecursiveDirectoryIterator( CHILD_DIR . '/less' );
$Iterator = new RecursiveIteratorIterator( $Directory );
$Regex = new RegexIterator($Iterator, '/^.+\.less$/i', RecursiveRegexIterator::GET_MATCH);

print_r( $Directory  );
print_r( $Iterator  );
print_r( $Regex  );
```

the output is the following:

```
RecursiveDirectoryIterator Object
(
    [pathName:SplFileInfo:private] => /var/www/secret/wayne/wp-content/themes/bootgen_child/less/bootgen_layout.less.bak
    [fileName:SplFileInfo:private] => bootgen_layout.less.bak
    [glob:DirectoryIterator:private] => 
    [subPathName:RecursiveDirectoryIterator:private] => 
)
RecursiveIteratorIterator Object
(
)
RegexIterator Object
(
    [replacement] => 
)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The comment doesn't tell the whole truth in this sentence

> $Regex will contain a single index array for each PHP file.

You actually need to iterate over `$Regex`, as a dump won't give you back a usual array

```
foreach($Regex as $file) {
  var_dump($file);
}
```

Comment: yeah thanks, i had something in mind about that because the first one contains only one this way. I need more experience with programming